# How do I limit fields fetched from related collections?

Tags: loopbackjs

I have simple chat setup with two collections `Room` and `Message`

What I am trying to do is fetch all rooms, and the last message in each room. So I tried:

```
Room.find({
        where:{
            or:[{myId:id},{partnerId:id}]
        },
        order:['updatedAt DESC'],
        limit:10,
        skip: (page-1)*10,
        include:[
            {
                relation:"messages",
                scope:{
                    where:{toId:id},
                    limit:1,
                    order:['createdAt DESC']
                }
            }
        ]},function(err,rooms){})
```

The above fetches only one message across all rooms, so essentially I have a hundred rooms and only one latest message in the resultset, whereas I want the last message in each room. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Your query is right. Are you sure you use correct from id's? I mean your data model matches with this query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your data model. But I think you need to remove `where` clause from `include`.

```
Room.find({
        where:{
            or:[{myId:id},{partnerId:id}]
        },
        order:['updatedAt DESC'],
        limit:10,
        skip: (page-1)*10,
        include:[
            {
                relation:"messages",
                scope:{
                    limit:1,
                    order:['createdAt DESC']
                }
            }
        ]},function(err,rooms){})
```